# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'namespace' (T_NAMESPACE)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, php-7

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'namespace' (T_NAMESPACE)
>   in CategoryController.php line 3

i got this error message after i route my web.php

my web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::resource('kategori','CategoryController',
                ['only'=>['index']]);

Route::resource('kategori', 'CategoryController', 
                ['except' => ['create', 'show']]);
```

my CategoryController

```
<?php
​
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
​
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Category;
​
class CategoryController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $categories = Category::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate(10);
        return view('categories.index', compact('categories'));
    }
}
```

is there any missing/wrong code on my project?
please help me fix this problem
any suggestion will very appreciate

Answer (score 0):

Remove one route from web.php and change route to

```
Route::get('kategori','CategoryController@index');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your web.php

```
Route::resource('kategori','CategoryController')->only(['index']);

Route::resource('kategori', 'CategoryController')->except(['create', 'show']);
```

Comment: sory doesnt work, the error move from CategoryController.php to web.php if i change => to ->

Comment: please create controller in console 

php artisan make:controller CategoryController --resource

then try it because it doesn't have create and show methods

Comment: Dont work either, if i make categorycontroller again it will show message "controller is already exist"

Comment: Keep your existing code as a backup then delete and create as i told you

Answer (score 0):

You can't use same controller for different resource,

```
Route::resource('kategori','CategoryController',
                ['only'=>['index']]);
```

But if you want to include other method.

```
Route::resource('kategori','CategoryController',
                ['only'=>['index', 'create', 'show']]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes im getting that error after push php file to server using ftp.Try to copy-paste your changes in your file.

Comment: welcome to stack overflow!  is it possible to link to an example or provide additional detail as to what/why this error is occurring, along with how to fix?